# How do I group my list by an attribute which can be null in SAP UI5?

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

Im trying to group a list of items from an entity called Services. I want to group them by the attribute group1_ID. The problem is that some Services dont belong to a group, in which case the value for group1_ID is Null.

Ive run it with generated mock data where every Service had values !== Null for group1_ID. In this case it worked fine with my original attempt.

What I had originally written was this:

```xml
<List id="_phaseOverviewList" 
   items="{ 
   path:'/Services',   
   sorter: {path: 'group1_ID', group: true}}">

   <StandardListItem id="_IDEGen_standardlistitem0" title="{name}"/>
</List>
```

I've also considered trying to sort it in the Controller.js for that View. I guess that would go in the direction of the following, but I'm not sure and I'm not sure how I should implement that.

```js
oList.getBinding(„items“).sort(new sap.ui.model.Sorter(„group_ID“, false, true));
```

I had hoped that the Services would be grouped based on the group1_ID attribute, and that Services with a Null value for group1_ID would be grouped together in the list. However, it just displays the list, unsorted/ungrouped.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There are no aggregation functions on the groups. The purpose is just for it to be clearer for the user visually. To display the services together based on what group they are in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the specs](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Sorter) what you do should already work, the null values should come at end. Instead of saying `group: true` you can provide a function that returns the group for each element. Something like this:

```
items="{ 
path:'/Services',   
sorter: {path: 'group1_ID', group: function(oContext){
let x = oContext.getProperty('group1_ID') || ''; //defaults to an empty string
return { key: x, title : x }}}}"
```

Have a look at https://gist.github.com/ikiw/bb2de7cd162bd88adf88 and for working examples. https://blogs.sap.com/2013/11/29/custom-sorter-and-grouper/